# Android SDK path - adb

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

I try to have the preview of my app with react native doing "npx expo start --tunnel".

I have a problem when i try to put "a" to have expo on android studio.

The problem was first with adb :

```
    › Opening on Android...
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: /home/quentin/Android/sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: /home/quentin/Android/sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
    Error: spawn adb ENOENT
```

I spend 3 hours to find a solution, impossible to solve it.

For info, I'm on windows, and I work on ubuntu.
I try to edit my zshrc file doing that ;

- nano ~/.zshrc
- Add (try much more multiple way to write it ...)

```
    export ANDROID_HOME="/mnt/c/Users/quent/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk"
    export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

- source ~/.zshrc

The android folder is located at : C:\Users\quent\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk, and adb is well present in the folder platform-tools

Then, I try to do

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

With this, the problem changes :

```
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
› Opening on Android...
Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: /home/quentin/Android/sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: /home/quentin/Android/sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: /home/quentin/Android/sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
CommandError: No Android connected device found, and no emulators could be started automatically.
Please connect a device or create an emulator (https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/android-studio-emulator).
Then follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.
```

I don't know what to do to solve the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

"For info, I'm on windows, and I work on ubuntu." What?

Are you using ubuntu or windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm on windows, but in a dev environment with WSL2 & Ubuntu defined as Windows sub-system for Linux as default

Comment: i guess the mount thing brings confusion here. The message says its looking for the SDK inside the /home/quentin/Android/sdk and its obviously not located there as you have it under C: windows machine. You could try to copy the whole SDK into this directory and try again

Comment: If I do that, I have to rename Sdk by sdk, and I have now the error "Error: spawn /home/quentin/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb ENOENT"